# Way to represent currying in anonymous class (conversion from lambda expression). Nested functions

Tags: java, lambda, anonymous-function

Hi I just want to check if my implementation and understanding is right. I trying to convert a sort of nested lambda into an anon class
`Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>>> h = x -> y -> z-> x + y + z`

Is this the appropriate way to represent this as an anon class?

```
Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>>> h = new Function <> ( 
int x, y;
@Override 
Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>> apply ( Integer x)

              return y-> z-> (x+y+z);
   }
};
```

Comment: Clearly the anonymous-class based function you wrote does not even compile. Also why is there some state associated with the anonymous function (`int x, y;`)? I've posted an answer below which I hope will explain things :)

Comment: Java isn't a language which really lends itself to such functional programming constructs. You *can* write curried functions, but my word, it is so ugly. What are you actually trying to do with this?

Comment: no actual practical implementation. I just wanted to understand how it would be implemented as an anonymous class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to convert a lambda to an anonymous function, you should decompose it bit by bit, each `->` corresponds to an anonymous Function instantiation, this would ends up to something like:

```
var h = new Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>>>() {
  public Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>> apply(Integer x) {
    return new Function<Integer,Function<Integer,Integer>>() {
      public Function<Integer,Integer> apply(Integer y) {
        return new Function<Integer,Integer>() {
          public Integer apply(Integer z) {
            return x + y + z;
          }
        };
      }
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! for your detailed answer.